# how can i apply different color to datapoint of ms chart?

Tags: c#, mschart

I am working on MS chart, not having so much idea.

I have bind the chart, my next thing is to give different colors of each datapoint?

How can i do that?

My sample code is:

```
 foreach (DataPoint pt in ChartRTM.Series["SeriesSeverity"].Points)
 {
      string sev = pt.YValues[1].ToString(); // this will be your value depending upon which you could set the color
      switch (sev)
      {
           case "I":
                pt.Color = Color.Red;
                break;
           default:
                pt.Color = Color.Blue;
                break;
      }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: ChartRTM.Series["SeriesSeverity"].Points is having zero count???

Comment: How are you binding it ?

Comment: I got, I was need to use datapoint in my chart control, but the thing is i need to bind datetime on Xvalues. So how to do that?

Comment: Try setting the `XValueType`, you have option of `Date` there

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change the **Marker color** of the point :

To do this, change the switch statement :

```
switch (sev) 
{ 
     case "I": 
          pt.MarkerColor = Color.Red; 
          break; 
     default: 
          pt.MarkerColor = Color.Blue; 
          break; 
}
```